# Can I avoid writing constructors that ONLY instantiate private variables in C#?

Tags: c#, class, constructor

I am new to C# and this sort of code is really painful to me, even just to look at...

```cs
private readonly Message.TypeEnum _type;
private readonly string _address;
private string _name;

public Endpoint(Message.TypeEnum type, string address, string name = null)
{
    _type = type;
    _address = address;
    _name = name;
}
```

Is there a better way? I am assuming not, but it's getting so redundant that I have to ask.

Comment: The answer is no, the compiler wont be able to read your mind to know how to fill a private variable, there has to be away to for it to know what you want. the only way is a constructor in your case

Comment: Also Google `Primary Constructors C#` for an approach that was considered but descoped.